# How to get bytecode from selected pdf in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to extract the bytecode from an file I select (pdf) to save it in my database. But I am always getting the error that my byte is undefined. Could someone look at my code and tell me what is wrong with it?

I tried to use the FileReader but my byte returns undefined, the formdata works fine it shows on the console every information I need for the file.

EDIT:

```
uploadFile2(files: FileList | null): void {
        const file = files.item(0)
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        reader.onload = () => {
          this.documentsArray.push({documentType: this.form.controls.dokumentType.value, file: reader.result})
          console.log(this.documentsArray)
        }
    }
```

Hi I edited my code and now I am getting a base64 I think, but one question, it starts like this:
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJfbk/N8KM......."

is the start with data:application/pdf correct or do I have to change something to save it in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to store the file as a base64 String in your database.
This would look as following. With the line number 2 you're fetching the file from your input event.

```
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = (event) => {
    if (reader.result) {
      //save pdf base64 into database
    }
```

Comment: Hi could you maybe show me how to do it with my example? I select a file through the fileupload which I open with my button click. I updated my code

Comment: I am getting this error: ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs.

Comment: I edited my code and tried to implement it like you said

Comment: I updated my code and came a step further could you please look at it when you get the time :)

Comment: @haso Hey, sorry for letting u wait, but when you get that data:application... String, this is totally fine. This is what we want here. When you get this string, you can just simply paste it into your database.

Comment: No problem at all I am happy you help me at all :) So I can save it into my database with the data/application part? It will be later sent with a service to my spring boot application, this is why I am asking

Comment: @haso For guaranteeing your performance between backend and frontend (micro service environment), It'd be helpful, if you'd use a compresser here. I'd suggest you to google up for a compression variant (library) you can use to make it smaller if it's possible on pdf's, since I've only tried it on images yet.

Comment: @haso Yes, you can just simply put it into your database. In the frontend you just call something like this: <a href="put your base64 string here" title='Download PDF' />

Comment: Thank you @tstdplt :) What do you mean with compressor? Do you know any library I can take an look at

Comment: @haso I'm not sure if compressing pdf's even work, but maybe try this library (didn't use it yet, and its been updated last time 3 years ago) https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pdf-compress-lib